# How can I update image using ReactJs and axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have problem to update my image using react and axios I convert it in a form data but can’t work it always affiche an error in axios data
This is my method to put data when I remove image in the axios data the request go to the api with success when i put image in the axios data the request is unsuccessful ;(

```
  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', this.state.images, this.state.images.name);
    console.log(fd);
    const { id, nom}  = this.state.patient;
    axios.put('/patients/' + this.props.match.params.id, {id, nom,fd})
      .then((result) => {
        this.props.history.push("/show/" + this.props.match.params.id)
        if (result.data != null){
          this.setState(this.initialState);
        
        }
      });
  }
```

This is my handler image

```
handleFile(e) {
    this.setState({ images: e.target.files[0] });
    this.setState({ image: '' });
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let images = e.target.files[0];
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      this.setState({ file: images, imagePreviewUrl: reader.result });
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(images)
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure the method is put and not post?

Comment: @Amin Darian yes i’m sure ,with this onSubmit method I can update all my data except the image file ;(

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?